# Comparing big theta values

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I am trying to order these different big theta values from largest to smallest:

```
Θ(n2)
Θ(2n log n)
Θ(n log n2)
Θ(2n2)
Θ(log n)
Θ(n log 2n)
Θ(k2)
Θ(22n)
Θ(n3)
Θ(n)
Θ(2n)
Θ(n1.5)
Θ(√n)
Θ(2n2)
```

and some of the values are equivalent. Particularly, I want to know if a constant term makes one big-theta value larger than an identical big-theta term without the constant term (for example, are these two values equivalent: Θ(22n) & Θ(n)?).

Comment: I think your could answer the question yourself if you thought about what does the notation represent.

Comment: Well, the main question I had was how to deal with values of the same order but different constant multipliers. I feel they are identical, but I wasn't sure how to order: Θ(n log n2) and Θ(n log 2n). The former is identical to log n3 and the latter is the same as log n2, but I wasn't sure if the former is considered larger than the latter?

Answer (score 1):

> Θ(log n)
>
> Θ(√n) = Θ(n<sup>1/2</sup>)
>
> Θ(n) = Θ(2n) = Θ(22n)
>
> Θ(n log n) = Θ(2n log n) = Θ(n log n<sup>2</sup>) = Θ(n log 2n)
>
> Θ(n<sup>1.5</sup>)
>
> Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) = Θ(2n<sup>2</sup>)
>
> Θ(n<sup>3</sup>)

---

Considering your comment:

> n log 2n = n (log 2 + log n) = n log 2 + n log n

`log 2` is a *constant non-zero value*, so:

> Θ(n log 2n) = Θ(n log 2 + n log n) = Θ(n + n log n) = Θ(n log n)

See the [sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-theta_notation#Sum) and [multiplication by a constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-theta_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant) properties of the big-{O,Theta, Omega}-notations.

Comment: How is O(nlogn2) equal to O(nlogn)?

Comment: @user2581779: A property of `log` function: `log(n*n) = 2*log(n)`, so `n*log(n*n) = 2*n*log(n)`. And multiplication by a constant does not matter for big-Theta.

Comment: I was wondering how O(nlogn) appeared and O(k2) disappeared in your results?

Answer (score 0):

If try replacing n with a huge value then you can figure it out yourself without even asking it to the forum:

```
o(1)
O(log log n)
O(log n)
O(n^c)
O(n)
O(n log n)
O(n^2)
O(c^n)
O(n!)
```